# how to get access_token passport-azure-ad in nestjs using OIDCStrategy

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, nestjs, passport-azure-ad

I'm using passport-azure-ad OIDCStrategy in nestjs app. The nest js app needs to communicate with other service secured by Azure Ad. To communicate with that service I need to provide an access_token. But in my code I configured `responseType: 'id_token code'` but only got code and id_token, state, session_state.

But in the doc, it says that "if you want access_token, use 'code', 'code id_token' or 'id_token code'."

So how can get the access_token in my nestjs app?

Thanks in advance for the solution.

Comment: Did you solve it yourself by any chance already? Would love to have your code shared